# Use C# async task with arguments as a function parameter

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm building my own queue based system but so far I have a small problem: How can I add an async Task to another function to process it?

My processor function works like this:

- I have a Queue object:

  ```
  public class Queue
  {
   public string Id;

   public CancellationTokenSource Cts;

   public Task Task;

   public Queue(Task task, string id, CancellationTokenSource cts)
   {
      Id = id;
      Cts = cts;
      Task = task;
   }}
  ```

And a command to add my tasks to 2 Lists: `List<Queue> ActiveQueues` and `List<Queue> Queued`

The ActiveQueues is a list with all the active queues, and Queued is a list with all queues.

My Add function looks like this:

```
public async Task Add(Task task, string id, CancellationTokenSource cts)
{
    var queue = new Queue(task, id, cts);
    if (ActiveQueues.Count < MainWindow.appConfig.MaxAsyncSessions)
    {
        var exists = ActiveQueues.Find(q => q.Id == queue.Id);
        if (exists == null) // I don't want 2 queues with the same id to run at once so I add it to the queued list that's processed by another function.
        {
            ActiveQueues.Add(queue);
            ActiveQueueIds.Add(queue.Id);
            await queue.Task;
        }
        else
        {
            Queued.Add(queue);
        }
    }
    else
    {
            Queued.Add(queue);
    }
}
```

The problem is that my task also has parameters so using it like `queue.Add(AsyncFunction(param1, param2), "idExample", new CancellationTokenSource())` triggers the function before adding it to the ActiveQueues list.

What would be the correct way to do what I want to do right now?

Comment: What problem is caused by triggering the `Task` before adding it to the queue?

Comment: Not related to your main question, but you can clarify your "exist"-check by using [`IEnumerable.Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__), which returns a `bool` instead of null or an object.

Comment: As a side note, there is already a [`Queue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1) class in BCL, so giving the same name to a custom class with completely different semantics can create confusion.

Comment: @CGundlach Yeah, I've changed it in the meantime:) Got confused with what triggers my second function when it should have been placed in the queued list.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I haven't noticed that thanks. But since only me and the customer has the code shouldn't be so confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `Add` method signature to accept delegate:

```
public async Task Add(Func<Task> taskFactory, string id, CancellationTokenSource cts)
```

And either change `Queue` ctor accordingly  and introduce method like `Start` which will start task (basically calling `taskFactory()`) and optionally having validation if it is already started and caching result of `taskFactory()` or use [`Lasy<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netcore-3.1) for handling it.

Simple implementation using `Lazy` can look like this (some code omitted for brevity):

```
class Queue
{
    public Lazy<Task> Task;
    public Queue(Func<Task> taskFactory)
    {
        Task = new Lazy<Task>(taskFactory);
    }
}

// in your Add method:    
var queue = new Queue(taskFactory);
await queue.Task.Value;

// Add call:
q.Add(() => AsyncFunction(param1, param2), "idExample", new CancellationTokenSource())
```

Comment: This can't be called with parameters for the `Func`, as OP requires.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay `Add(() => asynmethod(param1, pram2), ....)`, the problem is about triggering task as far as i understand?

Comment: Yes, so far the problem is that the task is triggered before calling it in the Add function